# Как правильно использовать VK api?

Tags: веб-программирование, ajax, вконтакте, javascript

Сразу хочу отметить, что являюсь разработчиком в другой, отличной от веба сфере, поэтому мне могут быть неизвестны/непонятны некоторые базовые аспекты программирования веб-приложений. Веб для меня непаханное поле.

Стоит задача:
Есть некоторый альбом в группе ВК, в котором пользователи группы размещают фотографии и картинки. Надо каким бы то ни было образом отобрать/отобразить/дать ссылки на худой конец на те фото, которые загрузили люди из определенного города (указанного в анкете автора фото).

Вопрос:
Каким образом и какими средствами можно реализовать? Можно ли тупо исполнить код в адресной строке, заюзав VK api и JS. Как мне видится, надо собрать данные на Клиенте, обратится на Сервер, потом вернуть данные с Сервера на Клиент и обработать. Или можно как-то иначе?

Поделитесь, кто что знает, у кого какие соображения по данной задаче... Если у кого есть мало-мальские примеры или еще что, буду рад.

Answer (score 1):

Всё можно и нужно делать на клиенте, если используется тип приложения Standalone.

Я вижу решение задачи следующим образом:

1. Получить список альбомов и определить ID по которому искать фотографии (метод [`photos.getAlbums`](http://vk.com/dev/photos.getAlbums))
2. Получить и отфильтровать изображения, с определением ID пользователя, загрузившего изображение (метод [`photos.getAll`](http://vk.com/dev/photos.getAll))
3. Получить информацию о местонахождении пользователя по его ID (метод [`users.get`](http://vk.com/dev/users.get))

Как завершающее действие - обработать все массивы данных и сформировать итоговый массив, содержащий нужную информацию.

Следует обратить внимание на количество запросов, которое может делать приложение. Стоит ввести задержку при исполнении запросов.

Как создать своё приложение можно найти на страницах [документации](http://vk.com/dev/main). Ну и писать это всё на JavaScript.